# How to get the CSS style attribute from HTML content using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing, css-parsing

I'm trying to get the Style attribute from the HTML div tag using Jsoup. See the below is my div tag.

```
<div id="badge" class="er-badge" style="width: 576px; height: 369px; background: url(&quot;http://localhost:1020/er/ERImg/firmUploads/13854/LogoImg4.png&quot;) 0% 0% / cover no-repeat; z-index: 1; position: relative;" tabindex="0" data-preview-purposes="checked">
```

from this div tag style I want to extract only the `background:` attribute. I can fetch the entire style properties using below code

```
String style = Element.attr("style");
```

But, I want to fetch only the background attribute value from this. Is it possible to extract that using Jsoup or Please tell any other easy way to extract the attribute.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to see this question instead of someone trying to use Regex to parse manually.

Just like [we should not parse html ourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), parsing CSS manually is also undesired.

There is already available library - <del>[cssparser](https://cssparser.sourceforge.net)</del> [htmlunit-cssparser](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.htmlunit/htmlunit-cssparser) to do the job. We can get the CSS value of `background` as below:

```
import org.htmlunit.cssparser.dom.CSSStyleDeclarationImpl;
import org.htmlunit.cssparser.parser.CSSOMParser;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ParseStyle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Element e = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("""
                <div id="badge" class="er-badge" style="width: 576px; height: 369px; background: url(&quot;http://localhost:1020/er/ERImg/firmUploads/13854/LogoImg4.png&quot;) 0% 0% / cover no-repeat; z-index: 1; position: relative;" tabindex="0" data-preview-purposes="checked"> 
                 """);
        String style = e.select("div").attr("style");
        CSSOMParser parser = new CSSOMParser();
        CSSStyleDeclarationImpl decl = parser.parseStyleDeclaration(style);
        System.out.println(decl.getPropertyCSSValue("background"));
    }
}
```

Comment: samabcde - Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried to implement the code but I couldn't see new SACParserCSS3(), I can able to import only new SACParser(). I couldn't use SACParserCSS3 in my application. I'm using maven.

Comment: Are you using version 0.9.30? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser/0.9.30

Comment: version 0.9.23... I could see SACParserCSS3.class in that Jar file when I extract that jar. Then Why I couldn't use that?

Comment: I don't see any problem using both version, I found a more actively maintained lib for css parsing and updated my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: The edited code uses https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.htmlunit/htmlunit-cssparser